# how to make a perticular column unique key for another column in mysql database table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two column in my database table `feeHead` and `className`. `feeHead` stores Tuition fee, Exam fee, Registration fee etc. and `className` stores 1st,2nd,3rd etc. I want to make `feeHead` column unique key for each `className`, meaning that each `className` value should have a unique `feeHead`. For example 1st class should have one Tuition fee, 2nd class should have one Tuition fee etc.

**one `className` (say 1st) should NOT have two `feeHead` (say Tuition fee, Tuition fee)**

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your table definitions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a composite `UNIQUE` key on `(feeHead, className)`. You can add one with:

```
ALTER TABLE fees ADD UNIQUE KEY (feeHead, className)
```

This will allow (for example), `classname` 1st to have a Tuition fee and an Exam fee, but not to have two Tuition Fees.